# Show for which constant the $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^y+ x^{2y}}$ converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm supposed to show for which $y>0$ the following Integral converges:

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^y + x^{2y}}$

I'm really stuck here and would really welcome help.

Comment: Near zero, the $x^{\gamma}$ term dominates and near infinity, the $x^{2\gamma}$ dominates. You need to come up with two necessary conditions for convergence at both ends.

Comment: I can't find any :( Could you give me one more hint?

Comment: Sure. $\int_0^c \frac {1}{x^p}dx$ converges iff $p\lt 1$. $\int_c^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p}dx$ converges iff $p\gt 1$.

Comment: thank you very much :)

Comment: If you make the change in the integral $t=x^y$ and then another change $s=\frac{1}{1+t}$ you will get $I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^y + x^{2y}}=\frac{1}{y}\int_0^1s^{1-1/y}(1-s)^{1/y-2}ds=\frac{1}{y}B(2-1/y;1/y-1)$$=\frac{1}{y}\frac{\Gamma(2-1/y)\Gamma(1/y-1)}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac{1}{y}\Gamma(2-1/y)\Gamma(1/y-1)$.  The function is defined for positives arguments of Gamma-functions, so $2-1/y>0$ and $1/y-1>0 \Rightarrow \,1/2<y<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to study the convergence of
$$\int_0^{+\infty}f_a(x)dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}dx.$$
We have to divide the domain of integration as $(0,\delta)\cup(\delta,+\infty)$.
The integral $\int_0^{\delta}f_a(x)dx$ converges iff the integrand is asymptotic to a convergent function in a nighbourhood of zero.
$\dfrac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}\sim\dfrac{c}{x^a}$ whose integral from zero to delta is convergent iff $a<1$.
In a neighbourhood of $+\infty$, $\dfrac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}$
is asymptotic to $\dfrac{c}{x^{2a}}$ whose integral is convergent iff $2a>1$, so if $a>\dfrac{1}{2}\implies \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}dx$ is convergent iff $\int_0^{\delta}\frac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}dx$ and $\int_{\delta}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^a+x^{2a}}dx$ are both convergent iff $\dfrac{1}{2}<a<1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry I edited the typo.

Comment: That's a good question :D

Comment: Better, f has convergent integral in $Cl(\mathbb B_r(x_0)\setminus\{x_0\}$, with $r>0$. Assuming $f$ continuous in $\mathbb R\setminus\{x_0\}$